# Best practice to expose part of your database to a 3rd party

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xml, csv, xslt

I am running a private Rails 3.2 web application on CentOS with MariaDB for different clients who generally should not be aware of each other and definitely should not be able to access each others data.

My application has around 80 tables, most of which have a `client_id` column to designate ownership of a specific client. Tables that don't can usually be joined on a table that does.

Using Rails I have written an abstraction layer for security that seperates these records based on the logged in client.

However, now I need to expose *all* data of a client to a third party application in order to do reporting in that 3rd party program. (Qlikview)

What would be a good way to accomplish this? I have already considered to following options:

1. Export CSV through Rails: Problems with newline and escaping content and performance.
2. Export XML through Rails: Problems with performance. Large table of ~500k records per client takes ~10-20minutes.
3. Export CSV through MariaDB with`INTO OUTFILE`: Problems with newline and escaping content.
4. Export XML through MariaDB: **Near perfect**, but program reading the XML, Qlikview, can't deal with `<field name="username"/>` naming tags and translating with XSLT is again very slow on large tables.
5. Enabling direct remote access to database over ODBC: No, just no!
6. Using Mysqldump with a `where`query and install local MySQL to restore into: Quite rigourous, but only valid solution I can currently think of. Qlikview would then pull data directly from local MySQL install over ODBC.

Wondering how others who ran into this problem have solved it! I can't be the only one.

Additional points:

- Data needs to be live. Changes need to be made in the app, and should immediately be reflected in any dump / transfer or download into the reporting tool. Scheduling a dump every 24h, for example, is not an option.
- Preferably I would also be able to restrict some columns for certain models, such as `hashed_password` in a `User` table.

Comment: Would have to go through Rails and suffer the same performance issues as attempt 1. and 2.. Having to instantiate 500k records from DB is simply too time consuming

Comment: Create views for your clients and grant them only read access to the views.

Comment: That still would require me to open remote access directly to my MySQL DB, something I prefer to avoid.